# Retrieving wxLogSysError on Ubuntu system log

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Trying to retrieve wxLog message on system log on Ubuntu platform:

Sample code:

```
char *log = "Log System error";
wxLogSysError(log);
```

Result:

```
Show dialog with status (warning dialog):
Log System error (error 0: Success)
```

And then trying to resolve where is stored log on Ubuntu `/var/log/*` or in `/var/log/syslog`. I didn't find any with `wx` or trying find sorted by time `ll -ltrha /var/log` and latest log is syslog but not mentioned with wxLog.

Tried as sample:

```
 cat /var/log/syslog | grep "wx"
```

No returned error logs for wx.

Where is stored error of `wxLogSysError(log);` function on Ubuntu system platform? Or how should be dealing with it? It's mentioned to errrno() or GetLastError() but how to store on system log?

References: 
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__log.html#ga28f01715af5aaf37caffdc5bc00fde3f

Debug mode didn't show any mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation that you linked explains, `wxLogSysError()` goes to exactly the same destination as `wxLogError()`, i.e. is shown in a dialog by default in a GUI program, and just appends the message corresponding to last system error (i.e. `errno` under Unix) to it.

So these messages never go to syslog. If you want syslog output, you'd have to implement your own `wxLog`-derived class to do it. You can also use existing `wxLogStream` or `wxLogStderr` classes to log to a file.

Comment: Thanks, it will be go to wxLogStream. That's what I'm trying to resolve.